# whats wrong with this code? want to redirect away if input match or echo out iframe if no match

Tags: php, string

Whats wrong with this code I want to redirect to page if there is a form input match or echo iframe if its not a match!

```
<?php

$stringname = "fieldname"

if(trim($stringname) == "fieldname") {

<?php header ("Location: https:www.google.com/"); ?>

}

else { echo "Iframe code here"; }

?>
```

Comment: <?php

$stringname = "fieldname"

if(trim($stringname) == "fieldname") {

<?php header ("Location: https:www.google.com/"); ?>

}

else { echo "Hello"; }

?>

Comment: Here is the code sorry

Comment: That looks horribly wrong - you cannot use `<?php` with a `<?php`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I make a redirect in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/768431/how-do-i-make-a-redirect-in-php)

Comment: Look especially at this https://stackoverflow.com/a/768472/3776927 answer, which provides various ways and describes various pitfalls in doing so ...

Comment: ok how should I do it? Im a newbie

Comment: `$stringname = "fieldname"` is missing an ending `;`. Also [How do I get PHP errors to display?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1053424/how-do-i-get-php-errors-to-display?rq=1) might be for you

Comment: thanks learned something new I a total newbie

Comment: `<?php header ("Location: https:www.google.com/"); ?>` should be `header ("Location: https:www.google.com/");` - you don't need `<?php` when you're already inside a `<?php` block.